# MS Word - Quick Parts' field update

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, field-codes

I have a MS Word protected document with some locked parts (not editable by users) and some editable fields (inserted by Quick fields> Field) that resume the value of some document properties (docProperty).

This is an example of my protected document:
[Locked MS Word document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mEqu5.jpg)

And these are the relative document properties:
[Document properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ltUlu.png)

Can I allow users to edit these fields inside the document and during the saving of the document overwrite the respective properties of the document?

Thank you very much,
PF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that by using "core properties" (title, status, comment,...) but you can't with "custom properties" or "extended properties".

;)

cy

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you did this: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Allow-changes-to-parts-of-a-protected-document-187ed01c-8795-43e1-9fd0-c9fca419dadf

and you want to know if people can overwrite the parts they're not allowed to.

The answer is no, because once **restricted** editing is on, nobody but the document's owner (and/or people with permissions to overwrite) can edit that part of the document.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, I did a restricted document, but I added exceptions for some fields in order to allow users to edit them (see your link > chapter "Protect a document and mark the parts that can be changed" > Point 5)

Comment: Ok, so they won't be able to edit the ones they can't but they will be able to edit the ones they can; if that makes sense.